# Spring RestDoc 1.1:MockMvcRestDocumentation.documentationConfiguration not working with JUnitRestDocumentation

Tags: spring-restdocs

I have configured as follows my rest docs with Junit4 ,with spring boot 1.4

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ActiveProfiles(SPRING_PROFILE_ACTIVE_TEST)
public class CustomerDetailsControllerWACTest {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext  wac;


    @Rule
    public final JUnitRestDocumentation documentation =
            new JUnitRestDocumentation("build/generated-snippets");

    private RestDocumentationResultHandler document;

    MockMvc mockMvc;


    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception
    {
        this.document = document("{method-name}", preprocessRequest(prettyPrint()), preprocessResponse(prettyPrint()));


        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(wac).
                apply(documentationConfiguration(this.documentation))
                .alwaysDo(this.document)
                .build();
    }
```

But the error is `The method documentationConfiguration(RestDocumentation) in the type MockMvcRestDocumentation is not applicable for the arguments (JUnitRestDocumentation)`

The documentation also has same configuration as mentioned here.But still it is showing above error.

RestDocs Dependancies(version):
spring-restdocs-core-1.1.1 and spring-restdocs-mockmvc-1.0.1

Comment: Can you add what exact version of spring-restdoc are you using? I use 1.1.2 and the exact same code does not show error. I currently have a problem that it does not output the snippet but it compiles and runs.

Comment: spring-restdocs-core-1.1.1 and spring-restdocs-mockmvc-1.0.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have incompatible version mismatch. You should use the same versions of core and mockmvc.

The `JUnitRestDocumentation` from `spring-restdocs-core` 1.1.1 cannot be applied to `MockMvcRestDocumentation.documentationConfiguration(RestDocumentation)` since that method in version 1.0.1 only accepts `RestDocumentation`. The overloaded method accepting the interface `RestDocumentationContextProvider` was added in 1.1.